# Authorize, let's encrypt issue?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

Recently found particpant 'contributions' using online CC payments were  missing trxn_id during a several hour period (Jan 31, 2019) - the civicrm_contribution and civicrm_financial_trxn rows were otherwise normal, so it appeared AuthorizeNet.php didn't return trxn_id in the result.
 AuthorizeNet returns errors if 1)it can't connect w/the payment gateway, 2)can't verify SSL, 3)verify the MD5 passcode, or if the payment is declined or CC # was wrong, but those errors would be surfaced in the UI (I think).
 Authorize did accept the payments and generated trxn_ids.  Is it possibly an SSL cert problem? I recently started using 'let's encrypt', anyone had a problem w/that?

Comment: Can you add civi version?

Comment: Sorry -  Civi 4.7.20 . And this is AIM transaction processing in Authorize fwiw.